# LevelQuik Primer did not dry to clear

Tags: primer, self-leveling-concrete

I sealed all gaps and applied [LevelQuik Primer](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Custom-Building-Products-LevelQuick-1-qt-Acrylic-Primer-and-Sealer-CPQT/100115970) over plywood in my bathroom to prep for [LevelQuik RS Self-Leveling Underlayment](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Custom-Building-Products-LevelQuik-RS-50-lb-Indoor-Outdoor-Self-Leveling-Underlayment-LQ50/100192482). I used a small paint roller to roll it on. It has not dried to clear and is still blue but feels dry to the touch. Any thoughts on if I should go ahead and pour the self-leveling underlayment?

Comment: Have you waited the recommended amount of time for your current temp & humidity conditions?

Comment: @FreeMan Yes primed it last night and it wasn't dry after 3 hours so I figured I'd see this morning since it's on the colder side in the room.

Comment: It doesn't dry completely clear. It dries to a transparent blueish film. Which I think is what you are seeing. So you are good. 
Also keep in mind they recommend pouring the self leveler within 12 hours or so. Can't remember the exact time. 
If it's past that time it's recommended to reprime.

Comment: @basement_diy thanks for clarifying. I did do a light reprime and let it dry then poured the self leveler. No issues!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be fine. Unless you applied it so thick that the very top skinned and sealed the surface so the product underneath is not drying.

Press on the darkest areas and maybe prick a small hole. If nothing seeps out you are ok.

( a secret not spoken of, is that many pros don't use the primer and still get great results.)

Comment: Thanks! No issues with the self leveler and looks great.

Comment: If you'll take the [tour], @Nate, you'll note that the proper way to say "thanks" is to click the up-arrow on all answers that help you and click the check mark for the one that helps the most. (Many questions get more than one answer, even though yours hasn't.)